# Missing leading hour zero on my digital clock

Tags: javascript

I tried to add the zero in front of the hour if hour is less than 12, but it only works on the minutes and seconds. I was not taught ternary yet so I can't use that as an option in my code.

I tried everything I could think of without using a ternary.
I am not even sure if I should use that many if statements in one function and I think that is why it is not working.

```js
let clock = document.getElementById("clock");
let color = document.getElementById("outermostDiv");

function clockTime() {
  let d = new Date();
  let h = d.getHours().toString();
  let m = d.getMinutes().toString();
  let s = d.getSeconds().toString();
  let AMorPM = document.getElementById("AMorPM");
    
    
  if(h.length < 2){
      h = "0" + h;
  };
  if(m.length < 2){
      m = "0" + m;
  };
  if(s.length < 2){
      s = "0" + s;
  };
  if (h == 0){
      h = 12;
  }; 
  if(h < 12){
      h = "0" + h;
      AMorPM.innerHTML = "AM";
  } else {
      AMorPM.innerHTML = "PM";
  };
  
  if(h > 12){
      h = h - 12;
  };
    
  document.getElementById("hours").innerText = h;
  document.getElementById("minutes").innerText = m;
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerText = s;
    
  setTimeout("clockTime()", 1000)
}
clockTime()
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Lato', Calibri;
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
    text-align: right;
}
#wrapper {
    min-width:1200px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
}
.outermostDiv {
    width:90%;
    
}
#clock {
    width:70%;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:10vw;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline;
    margin-top: 24vw;
    border-radius: .5vw;
}
#hours {
    /*width:15%;*/
    height:14vw;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:10vw;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:2vw;
    margin-left:6%;
    
}
#colon1 {
    /*width:15%;*/
    height:14vw;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:10vw;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:1vw;
    margin-left:1%;
}
#minutes {
    /*width:15%;*/
    height:15vw;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:10vw;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:2vw;
    margin-left:1%;
}
#colon2 {
    /*width:15%;*/
    height:14vw;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:10vw;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:1vw;
    margin-left:1%;
}
#seconds {
    /*width:15%;*/
    height:14vw;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:10vw;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:2vw;
    margin-left:1%;
}
#AMorPM {
    /*width:15%;*/
    height:6vw;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:3vw;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 4vw;
    margin-left:1%;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Digital Clock - EST</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="digitalClock.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC|Architects+Daughter|Covered+By+Your+Grace|Gamja+Flower|Give+You+Glory|Mansalva|Mrs+Saint+Delafield|Nanum+Pen+Script|Poor+Story&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body id="wrapper">
    
<div class="outermostDiv">
    
<div id="clock">
    
<div id="hours">

</div>
<div id="colon1">
:
</div>
<div id="minutes">
   
</div> 
<div id="colon2">
: 
</div>
<div id="seconds">

</div>
<div id="AMorPM">
  
</div><!--end of AM-->
</div><!--end of clock-->    
</div><!--end of outermostDiv-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="digitalClock.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your implicit type conversion is all over the place. You should make a strict differentiation between whether you are currently dealing with strings or numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting h to string, but then you are using it as integer, ending up converting it back in some cases. Move string conversion and the extra "0" addition to string toward the end, and you'll be fine. Like this.

```js
let clock = document.getElementById("clock");
let color = document.getElementById("outermostDiv");

function clockTime() {
  let d = new Date();
  let h = d.getHours();
  let m = d.getMinutes().toString();
  let s = d.getSeconds().toString();
  let AMorPM = document.getElementById("AMorPM");
    
  if(m.length < 2){
      m = "0" + m;
  };
  if(s.length < 2){
      s = "0" + s;
  };
  if (h == 0){
      h = 12;
  }; 
  if(h < 12){
      AMorPM.innerHTML = "AM";
  } else {
      AMorPM.innerHTML = "PM";
  };
  
  if(h > 12){
      h = h - 12;
  };

  h = h.toString()
  if(h.length < 2){
      h = "0" + h;
  };
  
  document.getElementById("hours").innerText = h;
  document.getElementById("minutes").innerText = m;
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerText = s;
    
  setTimeout("clockTime()", 1000)
}
clockTime()
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Lato', Calibri;
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
    text-align: right;
}
#wrapper {
    min-width:1200px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
}
.outermostDiv {
    width:90%;
    
}
#clock {
    width:70%;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:10vw;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline;
    margin-top: 24vw;
    border-radius: .5vw;
}
#hours {
    /*width:15%;*/
    height:14vw;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:10vw;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:2vw;
    margin-left:6%;
    
}
#colon1 {
    /*width:15%;*/
    height:14vw;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:10vw;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:1vw;
    margin-left:1%;
}
#minutes {
    /*width:15%;*/
    height:15vw;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:10vw;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:2vw;
    margin-left:1%;
}
#colon2 {
    /*width:15%;*/
    height:14vw;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:10vw;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:1vw;
    margin-left:1%;
}
#seconds {
    /*width:15%;*/
    height:14vw;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:10vw;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:2vw;
    margin-left:1%;
}
#AMorPM {
    /*width:15%;*/
    height:6vw;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:3vw;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 4vw;
    margin-left:1%;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Digital Clock - EST</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="digitalClock.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC|Architects+Daughter|Covered+By+Your+Grace|Gamja+Flower|Give+You+Glory|Mansalva|Mrs+Saint+Delafield|Nanum+Pen+Script|Poor+Story&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body id="wrapper">
    
<div class="outermostDiv">
    
<div id="clock">
    
<div id="hours">

</div>
<div id="colon1">
:
</div>
<div id="minutes">
   
</div> 
<div id="colon2">
: 
</div>
<div id="seconds">

</div>
<div id="AMorPM">
  
</div><!--end of AM-->
</div><!--end of clock-->    
</div><!--end of outermostDiv-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="digitalClock.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know it did, but see my second answer. Note that h-12 is also wrong. The am/pm 00 should be printer as 12.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) string method to prepend the leading zero to hours/minutes/seconds instead of doing it manually:

```
let clock = document.getElementById("clock");
let color = document.getElementById("outermostDiv");

function clockTime() {
  let d = new Date();
  let h = d.getHours().toString();
  let m = d.getMinutes().toString();
  let s = d.getSeconds().toString();
  let AMorPM = document.getElementById("AMorPM");

  if (parseInt(h) == 0){
      h = 12;
  }; 

  if (h < 12) {
    AMorPM.innerHTML = "AM";
  } else {
    AMorPM.innerHTML = "PM";
  };

  if (h > 12){
    h = h - 12;
  };

  const pad = value => value.toString().padStart(2, '0');

  document.getElementById("hours").innerText = pad(h);
  document.getElementById("minutes").innerText = pad(m);
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerText = pad(s);

  setTimeout("clockTime()", 1000)
}
clockTime()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do note, despite my initial answer, i'd really simplify it to something like this. Edit - loaded it into a snippet and made it run.

```js
function clockTime() {
  let d = new Date();
  
  let h = d.getHours();
  h = (h>12 ? h-12 : (h!=0 ? h : 12)).toString().padStart(2, '0');
  let m = d.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  let s = d.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  let ampm = d.getHours()<12 ? "AM" : "PM";

  document.getElementById("AMorPM").innerText = ampm;
  document.getElementById("hours").innerText = h;
  document.getElementById("minutes").innerText = m;
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerText = s;

  setTimeout("clockTime()", 1000)
}
clockTime();
```

```html
<span id="hours"></span>:
<span id="minutes"></span>:
<span id="seconds"></span>
<span id="AMorPM"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have made slight modification in your js code hope it works for you.

```js
let clock = document.getElementById("clock");
let color = document.getElementById("outermostDiv");

function clockTime() {
  let d = new Date();
  let h = d.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  let m = d.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  let s = d.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  let AMorPM = document.getElementById("AMorPM");
    
  
  if (h == 0){
      h = 12;
      AMorPM.innerHTML = "AM";
  } 
  
  else if(h<12){
      AMorPM.innerHTML = "AM";
  }
  else{
  AMorPM.innerHTML = "PM";
  h = h - 12;
  h=h.toString().padStart(2, '0')
  
  }        
  document.getElementById("hours").innerText = h;
  document.getElementById("minutes").innerText = m;
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerText = s;
    
  setTimeout("clockTime()", 1000)
}
clockTime()
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Lato', Calibri;
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
    text-align: right;
}
#wrapper {
    min-width:1200px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
}
.outermostDiv {
    width:90%;
    
}
#clock {
    width:70%;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:10vw;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline;
    margin-top: 24vw;
    border-radius: .5vw;
}
#hours {
    /*width:15%;*/
    height:14vw;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:10vw;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:2vw;
    margin-left:6%;
    
}
#colon1 {
    /*width:15%;*/
    height:14vw;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:10vw;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:1vw;
    margin-left:1%;
}
#minutes {
    /*width:15%;*/
    height:15vw;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:10vw;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:2vw;
    margin-left:1%;
}
#colon2 {
    /*width:15%;*/
    height:14vw;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:10vw;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:1vw;
    margin-left:1%;
}
#seconds {
    /*width:15%;*/
    height:14vw;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:10vw;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:2vw;
    margin-left:1%;
}
#AMorPM {
    /*width:15%;*/
    height:6vw;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size:3vw;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 4vw;
    margin-left:1%;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Digital Clock - EST</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="digitalClock.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC|Architects+Daughter|Covered+By+Your+Grace|Gamja+Flower|Give+You+Glory|Mansalva|Mrs+Saint+Delafield|Nanum+Pen+Script|Poor+Story&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body id="wrapper">
    
<div class="outermostDiv">
    
<div id="clock">
    
<div id="hours">

</div>
<div id="colon1">
:
</div>
<div id="minutes">
   
</div> 
<div id="colon2">
: 
</div>
<div id="seconds">

</div>
<div id="AMorPM">
  
</div><!--end of AM-->
</div><!--end of clock-->    
</div><!--end of outermostDiv-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="digitalClock.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```